# Javascript toISOString time in Golang

Tags: javascript, go, time, iso

I'm trying to generate ISO 8601 timestamp in Golang.

Doing

```
time.Now().UTC().Format(time.RFC3339)
//2016-04-12T19:32:20Z
```

in Javascript

```
new Date().toISOString()
//2016-04-12T19:46:47.286Z
```

It appears the only difference is in JavaScript the time reports milliseconds, while Golang it produces it in seconds. I'd like to try and get these to be the same.

I've looked at `time.RFC3339Nano`

But that produces too much precision `2016-04-12T19:35:16.341032697Z`

How can I get Golang to produce time that is equivalent to JavaScript's `toISOString()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From looking in pkg/time where the [constants are defined](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

```
RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
```

From the documentation:

> The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
>   Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
>
> To define your own format, write down what the reference time would look like formatted your way;

It should be something like so:

```
JavascriptISOString := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z07:00"
time.Now().UTC().Format(JavascriptISOString)
```

Comment: works great. strange that go doesn't have something like `RFC3339Milli` or something defined.. they go from seconds to nanoseconds

Comment: You're right, but the language designers tend to look for a minimum set (even if it sometimes excludes useful stuff).  At least it is pretty easy to make on your own.